# python sqlite giving errors

Tags: python, sqlite

I have python code that I am executing but it gives me following error:

```
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f3c7666dc00>
```

when I execute the cur.execute(statement). the code that is below the cur.execute is not read and nothing gets written. here is part of the code  i am using

```
statement = 'select "index",path,id from %s' %(table,) + " WHERE done IS NULL AND job = '%s';" %(job,)
cur.execute(statement)
for row in cur:
    print row
    pszFilename = row[1]
    name = os.path.basename(pszFilename)
    foo = int(name[2:4])
    if foo%2 == 0:
        meridian = foo + 1
    else: meridian = foo     
    print 'meridian: ',meridian
```

Comment: Seems not a GIS question, perhaps you should consider moving it to StackOverflow?

Comment: Try printing statement to make sure it really looks like you expect it to, and then try that in the sqlite shell as suggested by kyle.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess it is working, but your sql returns no rows.  Try hooking up to the database with the sqlite3 shell and check your sql.  I've found that sqlite is pretty quiet with incorrect sql (tables don't exist, etc).  Another observation, although it's a guess, since you posted on the GIS forum and use the GDAL like variable name pszFilename, you can use the ogr sqlite driver to read from a sqlite database.  Fetch a layer, set an attribute filter on the layer and iterate through the features.